# Bootstrap form does not align with h1 in with search form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The search form is not centrally (vertical) aligned in the jumbotron like the heading Sellr Buyr. Here is the code. Although I know padding or adding a margin will help.

I need the "class" to insert that aligns it perfectly well in large and medium screens.

Here is my Code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sellr Buyr</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="keywords" content="keywords1, change later">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->
        <!-- stylesheets and js paths must be updated later -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_sources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_sources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <header>
           <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container"><!--fluid container-->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-header"><!--nav-header-->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage">$ SellrBuyr</a>
                    </div><!--/nav-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"><!--main-nav-collapse-->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">LOGIN<i class="caret"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">REGISTER<i class="caret"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="btn-danger"><a href="#">PUBLISH YOUR AD FOR FREE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div><!--/main-nav-collapse-->
                </div><!--/fluid container-->
            </nav>

            <div class="jumbotron"><!--jumbotron-->
            <div class="container"><!--container--> 
            <div id="logo" class="col-lg-6"><!--logo-->
            <h1>Sellr Buyr</h1>
            <span id="description">Sell Buy Hire Rent in India - Goods Services Products Property - Jobs and Matrimonial Services - Post Free Classified Ads Online</span>
            </div><!--/logo-->

            <div class="col-lg-6 "><!--col-lg-6 -->
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- col-lg-6 -->

            </div><!--/container-->
            </div><!--/jumbotron-->
        </header>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can do that as you want.

You have to "fix" height in order to do that and then play also with the media-queries.

I will suggest you to look here how to vertical align:

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Let me know what you think and will try to help you with some workaround.

Comment: do i really need to play with media queries? it makes me sad. any bootstrap class to vertically align both header and search vertical centrally? header is already aligned but the search form is not please help.